# How to open a bottle that won't open

Tags: food, kitchen, packaging

So sometimes when I leave bottles of sauce in the pantry too long, the lid seems to "stick" to the bottle and won't allow me to open it. **How can I open the bottle when it doesn't want to open?** Below is the bottle I'm talking about

[image: Dolmio bottle]

I know about the method where you tip it upside down in hot water/run it under hot water to expand the metal that little bit. Are there other methods/ways to open it short of breaking the jar?

Comment: try a wet ea towel aroudn the cap and gripping it tightlyh